# Is std::type_info access after the dll is closed (dlclose)

Tags: c++

I have a main dll，the following code is defined:

```cpp
class TypeInfo
{
public:
     explicit TypeInfo(const std::type_info& typeInfo)
          : typeInfo_(&typeInfo)
     {
     }

public:
     template <class T>
     static const TypeInfo& FromType()
     {
          static TypeInfo result(typeid(T));
          return result;
     }

public:
     const std::type_info& TypeInfo::GetOriginType() const 
     { 
          return *typeInfo_; 
     }

     size_t HashCode() const
     {
          return std::hash<std::type_index>()(GetOriginType());
     }

private:
    const std::type_info* typeInfo_;
    // ....
};

namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<TypeInfo>
    {
        typedef TypeInfo argument_type;
        typedef size_t result_type;

        size_t operator()(const TypeInfo& key) const 
        { 
            return key.HashCode(); 
        }
    };
}
```

```cpp
class Container
{
public:
   // ...

private:
   std::unordered_map<TypeInfo, std::shared_ptr<void>> map_;
}
```

Accessed it in another dll （loaded through dlopen），It create `TypeInfo` and saved in the `std::map` (used as a key) of the main dll.

When the program ends the dynamically loaded dll was closed by dlclose. can the `std::type_info` saved in the main dll still be used at this moment?

I encountered this problem because I was designing an ioc container. The dll loaded through dlopen might register something in the container. I know that the resources belonging to the dll will be closed, but I am not sure whether std::type_info is still valid. (The cleaning of the container lagged behind dlclose)

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but please show the declaration of your `std::map`.

Comment: I doubt that'll work. The `type_info` instance for a type implemented in a DLL likely uses static data structures in that DLL's data segment. When the DLL is unloaded, that data is gone, too. The pointer `TypeInfo` holds will become dangling.